# High memory, slow responsiveness

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, memory

I have x86 WPF application, application displays quite a lot of data with a live streaming from RabbitMQ. Application starts at about 500 MB of memory, but during the day, since users load more and more data it may go up to 900-1000 MB. As soon as it hits around 900 MB threshold application becomes very slow, not that much responsive. For example, editing DevExpress grid takes time (I must admit, that each modification triggers plenty of LIVE actions, but it is all good when memory is below 900MB).
Users have high spec machines (i7 CPU, 128 GB RAM), plenty of free resources.

We diagnosed application for the memory leaks, CPU usage, and everything is OK. Grow from 500MB to 900MB is expected, since more data is loaded.
From what I understand x86 is limited to 2GB, but for me application is slow (+ starts throwing out of memory exceptions at around 900 MB).
What should we do? What needs to be checked?

Comment: Store data from MQ in local storage(fx SQLite) load only what is needed ... I don't belive that user need all almost 1GB of data loaded at the same time ...

Comment: What does your profiler say?

Answer (score 1):

If you can, switch to x64. by now there should be little reason for 32-bit code, unless you are using some really ancient libraries.

It also depend on what you are measuring, i.e. total process memory, or actual memory used. A memory profiler should give you the later. The garbage collector will need a bit more memory than is actually used, however 100% overhead seem a bit much.

Another possible reason is memory fragmentation. While small memory allocations will be automatically de fragmented/compacted, larger allocations (85kb+ last I checked) will be placed on the Large Object Heap (LOH), and this is *not* automatically compacted. This could lead to situations where there is plenty of memory available, but not any single "hole" large enough to fulfill the memory request. A good memory profiler should give you some idea about the degree of LOH fragmentation. See also [The large object heap on Windows systems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/large-object-heap)

The LOH can be manually compacted by running

```
GCSettings.LargeObjectHeapCompactionMode = GCLargeObjectHeapCompactionMode.CompactOnce;
GC.Collect();
```

But this is kind of a bandaid. Moving to x64 would be better, and using some kind of memory pool that allocates fixed size blocks to avoid fragmentation would probably be best.

As a rule of thumb, .Net works best when allocations are small and really short lived, or stay alive for the entire application lifetime. The former will be handled by the Gen0/1 (i.e. fast) collections, and the later placed in gen2/LOH, and never collected.
High frequency, large, variable sized allocations is probably the worst case scenario for the garbage collector/memory allocator.